# GeoTools FeatureCollection to Filter (make Filter from a FeatureCollection)

Tags: java, geotools, filter

I have a FeatureCollection and I want to make a Filter of them. One way is that I may use `FilterFactory#id(Set<Identifier> set)` to make a filter.

```
FilterFactory ff = CommonFactoryFinder.getFilterFactory();
Set<String> idSet = DataUtilities.fidSet(collection);
for(String s : idSet) {
   fidSet.add(ff.featureId(s));
}
Filter filter = ff.id(fidSet);
```

Is that the best way?
How can I do that? How can I get rid of the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the loop by peeking inside `DataUtilities` and seeing how it collects the `String` ids - this leads to the following code:

```
Set<Identifier> fidSet = new HashSet<>();
try {
  collection.accepts(new FeatureVisitor() {
    @Override
    public void visit(Feature feature) {
      fidSet.add(feature.getIdentifier());
    }
  }, null);
} catch (IOException e) {
  // TODO Auto-generated catch block
  e.printStackTrace();
}
Filter filter = ff.id(fidSet);
```

which should be faster than converting all the IDs to strings and back again.